# Multi Level Relationships and Models in Yii

Tags: php, yii

How do I get the model of relationships? (and then the models of those relationships)

Maybe something like below, but im stuck:

```
$model = Store::model()->findByPk($_GET['id']);

$relation = $model->getMetaData();

$relation = $relation->relations;

foreach($relation as $name=>$relation){

  $model_of_relation = ??;

}
```

Comment: what you want to do with that models ? you can use $model->relations, it will return your relations specs array. 
then if you want to get any relation use method $model->getRelated(relationName)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
$model = Store::model()->findByPk($_GET['id']);
foreach($model->relations as $relatedModel) {
    $model_of_relation = $model->getRelated($relatedModel);
    // ... Other processing of $model_of_relation ...
}
```

Comment: I realized... maybe you want to 'discover' the relationships that this table has, from the metadata...? If that's the case you'll have to look at the database and/or override the relations() function in your 'Store' class. See [link](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/database.arr)